# Visual studio 2010 ajax control toolkit tab container

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabcontainer

We just upgraded to visual studio 2010 RC1 and all of a sudden our controls inside tabcontainer disappeared from the designer file.

Actually, it all seemed good in the beginning, the project compiled nicely, but as soon as we did any change in the markup of a page and build the code for the controls inside the tabcontainer disappeared and we got errormessages like so

```
"Error 3 The name 'ddlPeriodicityStartInMonth' does not exist in the current    context "
```

Does anyone know if any changes are made to tabcontainer to visual studio 2010 or if this just is a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Check out the following link:

[Microsoft Connect - Bug in generating the designer.cs file in VS2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536000/bug-in-generating-the-designer-cs-file-in-vs2010-converting-vs2008-project-to-vs2010)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one also.

[Workaround: Missing Declarations for Controls in Designer File](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2010/02/18/workaround-missing-declarations-for-controls-in-designer-file.aspx)